# Origin of the neologism "radiodrome"

Tags: greek, neologism

In the [Wikipedia entry of the term "radiodrome"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiodrome) for a pursuit curve, there arose a question about its original intended meaning:   *ῥᾴδιος+δρόμος*, or *radius+δρόμος*.
I have been unable to find suitable dictionary entries for the word, which might shed light on its earliest usage, appearance, and intended evocation in the neologism.

Is there an older attestation of the term? For example, ["*brachistochrone*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve) goes back to the 17th century.

Comment: I believe Wikipedia's source for the etymology, ῥᾴδιος+δρόμος, is "The Mathematics of Pursuits and Evasion" by Paul J. Nahin. Contrary to what I originally thought, the article originally had the Laitn-Greek etymology, but it later updated it to the Greek (in 2016), and I believe the change was due to Nahin's book.